# Flattening data using Object.Assign and dealing with null/undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Say i'm using @wire to return a query of multiple fields but i need to flatten out three relationship fields to display their record names

```
this.tableData = data.map(
                record=> Object.Assign(
                    { "SomeField1": record.SomeField1__r.Name},
                    { "SomeField2": record.SomeField2__r.Name},
                    { "SomeField3": record.SomeField3__r.Name},
                record
                    )
            );
```

The problem is sometimes those fields wont have a value and what will happen is i get an error:

```
[Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined]
```

My work around has just been never to use object assign, but that means i have to flatten out **all the data**.  This takes more lines of code and much more time, it's fairly ugly and inconvenient. Anyone know a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a
> property located deep within a chain of connected objects without
> having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.
> The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of
> causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined), the
> expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined

for example

```
 { "SomeField1": record?.SomeField1__r?.Name}
```

furthermore, you can default it to an empty string using a [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), if the value evaluates to undefined,

```
{ "SomeField1": record?.SomeField1__r?.Name ?? ''}
```

Comment: There's a problem as that doesn't seem to work within the Object.Assign context, at least in LWC. You get the error [Object.Assign is not a function]]. with either method.

Comment: @ensir It's `Object.assign`, not `Object.Assign`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make things easier, plus the null safe operator.

```
this.tableData = data.map(
  record => ({
    ...record, 
    SomeField1: record.SomeField1__r?.Name,
    SomeField2: record.SomeField2__r?.Name,
    SomeField3: record.SomeField3__r?.Name
  })
);
```

`Object.Assign` is not a function. JavaScript is case sensitive, so you must always take care to use exactly the correct case in the documentation.

The spread operator is roughly equivalent to Object.assign; it does not flatten an object, but it does copy all of the properties in a simple manner.